# Program for Tv Tuner

Tags: c#, c++, windows, television

I want to develop my own tv tuner program mainly for live stream.
Looked at OpenCV but I still prefer to have something that I own, mainly due to customization.

Search over the web and cant seem to find a good site on how to start.
The only clues that I have are things like `DirectX`, `DirectShow`.
From what it seems, i believe web cam and tv tuner works about the same way, but correct me if I am wrong. So can I say that I need to detect video capture device, or is it another type of device.

Will need help from you expert out there. Platform wise will be windows. Language wise I think C++ will do.C# is also good for me.

Comment: @DumbCoder: CPP stands for C Plus Plus.  I am not aware of any other programming languages that "CPP" would likely be referring to.

Comment: U mean CPP is not C++? Anyway is C++, used to typing CPP

Comment: New nomenclature for C++, haven't heard of it till now except for file naming.

Comment: @Brian: No, CPP stands for C PreProcessor. It is one of the most abused acronyms in C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: @0A0D thanks for the clarification. I used to think CPP also refer to C++ as u go google and type CPP, it gives u examples in C++

Comment: @Brian: hahaha, CPP = C Plus Plus. hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.  Both the tuners and webcam allow you to read a strream. The tuner also allows you the change the channel etc.

A good point to see how it all works is MediaPortal an Open Source .net HTPC applicaiiont

http://www.team-mediaportal.com/

Comment: OK, at least I know where to start looking for.
I was hoping I can incorporate switching channel too.
But given the response, guess I can only stream

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a TV tuner in software.  CPUs are still many orders of magnitude too slow to decode the TV signal from the carrier frequency.  Hardware is required, [Hauppauge](http://www.hauppauge.com/) is in the business of TV tuner cards.

Comment: Yup have hardware, issue is just that some users have their preferred hardware, but I would prefer if I can do 1 program to cater for most of the hardware. That is, 1 TV tuner hardware, and 1 software which is for me to customize.